# iphone - data signing using NSData of the private key

Tags: iphone, rsa, nsdata, signing, keychain

I am working on a e-banking iphone application.
I am using WSS with XML-Signature to sign the requests to the customer's SOAP server.
Since the iPhone device can not be trusted (due to jail-breaking), the customer
requirement is to manually encrypt the RSA key pair (using AES128) before storing the keys into keychain.

From what I have found so far, the keys are automatically added to the keychain when generated.
So my idea is to extract the data afterwards (the same way the public key is extracted in the CryptoExercise example), remove the keys from keychain, do the AES encryption and store it again into keychain as a custom NSData.

1) Do you see any problem with this ?
I read somewhere that retrieving the data or deleting the key might require some sort of password, although I didn't got what password. I will try this later today and will post the answer if no answer is posted in meantime :)

2) I can not find if there is any way to use this key without implementing some more hacks in the code?
It seams like the SecKeyRawSign method only accepts a SecKeyRef reference which is a pointer to the key in keychain. Is there some other method for signing using the NSData of the key ?
The only idea I have in the moment is to use SecItemAdd method to add the non-encrypted key into the keychain before signing, and remove it after signing. But I don't like this since it will happen all the time, and if the application is shut down (crashes or something) before the key is removed from keychain it will remain there until lets say the next time application is started.

Any idea for a better solution ?

regards

Comment: After a whole day of trials and failures I finally managed to do the following:  
- generate key pair  
- get the bytes of the keys  
- remove the keys from key chain  
- add them again using the SecItemAdd method  
- use the private key to sign some data  

So the only thing that is left is to encrypt the key before storing manually and then as I said in 2) whenever I need it I will get the encrypted key, decrypt it, add it to keychain, do the signing and then remove the unsigned key. If this is too much to be done on every request I might do it once per app run.

Comment: just a hint if anyone is having troubles signing the data once you add the private key manually, don't forget to set the kSecAttrKeyClass attribute to kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate when you prepare your dictionary for the SecItemAdd method.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but the Apple CDSA mailing list is a good place to ask this question http://lists.apple.com/mailman/listinfo/apple-cdsa

Answer (score 1):

Consider checking Apple example and documentation for Security. Framework:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001358-CH208-SW13 - see this link

Comment: Dead link. The page cannot be found.